# Array resorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I have a list items from which some of them are missing, like for example, here 3rd in order is missing:

```
<ol>
   <li data-id='0'>Apple</li>
   <li data-id='1'>Banana</li>
   <li data-id='3'>Tea</li>
   <li data-id='4'>Biscuit</li>
</ol>
```

I also have an array the same length as the number of list items which contains data for each list items (here also 3rd item is missing, 'c'):

```
var arr = ['a','b','d','e'];
```

After I remap this into new array:

```
var ordered_array = jQuery('ol li').map(function() {
    return arr[jQuery(this).data('id')];
}).get();

 console.log(ordered_array);
```

I get:

```
["a", "b", "e"]
```

Why is it loosing one item? ('d')

Comment: The values of the attributes should probably be 0, 1, 2, 3, not 0, 1, 3, 4.

Comment: Yes, but I have deleted 3rd (in this example) so I am trying to remap it, but without changing id again, is it possible?

Comment: @Toniq: Rather than *removing* the value from `arr`, set it to `undefined`/`null`; `var arr = ['a','b', null, 'd','e'];`

Comment: No, I cant do that, I have to remove it.

Comment: Ok, so why does `data-id` have to refer to the element index? Can't it contain the element directly? The easiest option would be to update the `data-ids` when you remove an element (include "@Matt" in your response, so I get a notification when you reply).

Comment: I shouldnt actually touch data-id atts because these li elements can be ordered differently before I remap them. So not only some of them might be missing but the order of existing ones could change, and I need to keep the order of my 2 arrays (one containing the li items, the other their data)

Comment: The problem is that if your array is like `['a','b','d','e']`, you actually don't know which of the elements is missing, if any. It's impossible, without reassigning the indexes. Maybe you want to have a look at knockout.js for binding data to UI: http://knockoutjs.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Because if you return an `undefined` or `null` value from the `map()` callback, no entry for that element is included in the returned array ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)).

In this case, `data-id="4"` for `Biscuit`, but `ar[4] === undefined`, hence it is not included in the returned array.

Comment: And `Tea` (`data-id=3`) maps to `e`.

Comment: How do I make it map all the items?